# Webpack app.js Not Being Loaded Into HTML Script Tag After Packaging with Electron-Builder

Tags: reactjs, linux, electron, electron-packager, appimage

I am trying to build a React app using Electron-Builder. Right now, I have a simple template with a file structure like this:

```
Project
+
|
+--node_modules/
|
+--build/
|  |
|  +--js/
|     |
|     +--app.js
|
+--src/
|  |
|  +--js/
|     |
|     +index.js
|     |
|     +app.js
|
+index.html
|
+main.js
|
+package.json
|
+webpack.common.js
```

`Webpack.common.js` is a boilerplate config file that gives `src/js/index.js` as the entrypoint for webpack. `src/js/index.js` is the entry point for the react app. `src/js/app.js` defines a simple hello world react app that gets rendered by `src/js/index.js`. Webpack takes `src/js/index.js` and creates `build/js/app.js`, which is then included in `index.html` as the `src` for a `<script>` tag. `main.js` just defines a basic electron app that loads `index.html` via:

```
win.loadFile('index.html')
```

Here are the relevant parts of the `package.json` file:

```
...

"scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --config webpack.common.js --watch",
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "postinstall": "electron-builder install-app-deps"
},
"build": {
    "linux": {
        "target": [
            "AppImage"
        ]
    }
},

...
```

This setup works great when running `npm start` to run the electron app in dev mode. This boots up the electron app and my *hello world* app shows on the screen. However, when I package the app using `npm run dist` then run the AppImage file that gets produced, I get a blank window with nothing on it. After some tinkering, I realized the issue is related to `index.html` loading `build/js/app.js` as a script. In fact, if I copy `build/js/app.js` to the root as `app.js` and modify `index.html` to read

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="./build/js/app.js"></script>
```

then the AppImage runs fine.

What do I need to do to get the build version to run properly using the `build/js/app.js` script produced by webpack?

Note that this is my first time trying to package an app using electron-builder and I don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding:

```
“files”: [
“**/*”,
“build/js/app.js”
]
```

To the “build” object in `package.json`